# Iterating in ModelBuilder to Generate Output Files in Source Folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I have a very simple model that has a feature class iterator (recursive) that runs through a directory and sub-folders looking for line files and then projects them to UTM_16N. The only issue with the model is the destination for the output files.
[image]

Instead of having all the outputs going to a single destination I want them to be created in the source folder. So basically the model would dump the output in the same folder as the source file.

There are hundreds of folders each containing an individual line file and they all have the same name. The only identifier so to speak is the container folder name (counties in this case).

Comment: Best to ask a specific question. asking for advice does not fit the model of this site.  See help "how to ask".  http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subtle change to your model. See the image below:

[image]

Configure **Expression** parameter of **Calculate Value** like this:

[image]

Set **Output Dataset or FeatureClass** parameter of **Project** tool to %output_value%